# Easiest system of equations to solve

Tags: systems-of-equations

Suppose we need to solve the following system of equations:

$$
\left\{\begin{align*}
&f_1(x_1) + f_1(x_2) + \ldots + f_1(x_k) = a_1,\\
&f_2(x_1) + f_2(x_2) + \ldots + f_2(x_k) = a_2,\\
&\vdots\\
&f_k(x_1) + f_k(x_2) + \ldots + f_k(x_k) = a_k,\\
&1 \le x_1 < x_2 < \ldots < x_k \le n\\
&x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k\in \mathbb{N}
\end{align*}\right.
$$
However, the functions $f_i$ can be chosen freely before the system is formed.

Obviously, for $k = 1$ choosing the identity function $f_1(x)=x$ is the easiest.
For $k = 2$ we can have $f_1$ as an identity and $f_2$ as a quadratic function, which would give a quadratic equation.

In general, we could have chosen $f_k(x)=x^k$, and then use some numeric methods to solve the resulting system, but I wonder if there's perhaps a better choice for the functions $f_i$ which would make solving the system easier?

Comment: With $f_k(x)=x^k$ it is straightforward to use [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) to determine the $n^{th}$ degree polynomial whose roots are $x_1, x_2,\dots,x_n$. Given the roots are known to be integers, they can be then be found with the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).